# WPF binding combo box object to datagrid list of objects

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'll create an example that gives a simplification of my problem. I have a WPF view that consists of 2 datagrids and a combobox.

Datagrid 1 - List of classes

Datagrid 2 - List of students in the selected class

Combobox - All students

My aim is to select students within the class using the combobox. I want to be able to bind the selected student from the combobox to the currently selected student in datagrid 2.

I can update datagrid 2 from the selection made in datagrid 1 without any problems. The issue I am facing is when trying to bind the combo box object to the selected item of datagrid 2.

The XAML for datagrid 2 is as follows:

```
<DataGrid 
    Name="dataGridClass" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedClass.Students}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedStudent, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

The XAML for the combobox is as follows:

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="comboStudent" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Students}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

When I select the student using comboStudent I would like the currently selected student in dataGridClass to reflect the new combobox selection. I want the combobox to have two way binding so that if a student is selected using dataGridClass then the value in the combobox will also update to reflect this.

Currently when the comboStudent value is selected, it has no effect on the dataGridClass (and vice versa). This is not a notify property changed issue as I can see that the underlying list SelectedClass.Students also remains unchanged.

I had started to HACK my way around this issue but it started to get really dirty, really quickly. I feel like I am missing something obvious here but can't quite get it to work. I had a scout through the site but didn't find anything that fixed my issue. I have lots of other binding working within my application as I would expect so it feels as if the binding of full objects from one source to another works in a slightly different way.

Any help would be massively appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Please explain exactly, fully, precisely, concretely, and unambiguously both the *expected behavior* and the *observed behavior* you're alluding to in this sentence: "the SelectedClass.Students array is never updated and there does not appear to be a connection between the selected student and the student list in the selected class". And please do it in the question, not in a comment. Also note how the XAML snippets are now formatted in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ed. I have updated the question.

Comment: Please update as I requested.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did not set the `DataContext` of your objects.

Comment: It sounds like the controls are populated.

Comment: The controls are populated yes. The view model is bound and data is visible on the page. The issue is the binding between the dataGridClass and comboStudent. When a student is selected in comboStudent, the selected item in dataGridClass does not update (and vice versa). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly guess that the object identity is not given. The binding of `SelectedItem` of your `ComboBox` searches for the exakt identical item which is selected in your `DataGrid`. I assume that you got two lists with students, one which populates the ComboBox and one which is a property of your class.

First of all you could try to select `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`, which compares the equality of an object instead of reference-equality. You should implement `IEquatable<Student>` then (you should do this anyway if you haven't). This could help you with your `ComboBox`, but still will not update the DataGrid 2 when you select something in the `ComboBox`.

You could work around this other issue with a selection changed handler, but I would try to use the same students-objects within your lists, e.g. use `Linq` to get an `ILookup<Student>` for a set of lists for the classes.

It would help to see the implementation your property `Students`.

**edit:** as Ed Plunkett mentioned, there is a `SelectedValuePath` on the ComboBox which you could use to update your `SelectedValue`. This is in most cases used in combination with the `DisplayNamePath` which you already used. So you do not need to compare a full item (which would be the default) on equality, but can also use e.g. `DisplayNamePath="Name"` to select the student with the same full name. Then you would not be forced to implement `IEquatable<Student>` but check only one property of `Student` instead. This does not solve the update of your DataGrid either, but it is good to know anyway.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, I do have two lists of students. Both the student list within the selected class and the student list that populates the combobox are defined as : 

public ObservableCollection<Student> Students;

I will try the suggestions that you have made and report back. Thank you.

Comment: @Herm please explain how SelectedValuePath works with SelectedValue